# How to show a notification when the previously entered date arrives

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to make a reminder app, but I can't find out how to show if the entered date is the current date. To give an example:

> I added a reminder on December 19, 2021 at 17:45, and I want to know if this date is before today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datetime.datetime.strptime() to convert string to datetime object. Then you can calculate time delta with to check how much time is left.

```
import datetime

reminder = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/19/2021, 19:11:14',
                                      "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

print(datetime.datetime.now()) # 2021-12-12 17:24:01.573420
time_delta = reminder - datetime.datetime.now()
print(time_delta.seconds) # 6432
print(time_delta.days) # 7
```

If the current date is after the reminder date, days will be negative.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. It's works but  when I write the codes you say, it only detects whether the day has passed or not. But I want to see this even when the time has passed, for example: when the time is set to 17:45, I want to detect it even when the local time is 17:46

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python's builtin datetime module.

You can import it like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

To convert the reminder string to a date time object, you can use the `strptime()` function.

```py
reminder_date = "December 19, 2021 at 17:45"
reminder = datetime.strptime(reminder_date, "%B %d, %Y at %H:%M")
```

Next, get the current datetime object.

```py
current = datetime.now()
```

Finally, you can compare them using python's builtin comparison operators as follows.

```py
if reminder < current:
    print("passed")
else:
    print("future")
```